# MySQL cannot create file (permission denied). even my folder permission is 1777 (Ubuntu)

Tags: mysql

hello I have some issue with my MySQL db. I've try so many ways to fix it, but it cannot solve my problem. I tried this [Cannot output MySQL data to file](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17029/cannot-output-mysql-data-to-file?newreg=1ce70790c5c849c3922c11983bacac8d). and still have same error.

this is my query and error result :

> mysql> select * from categories into outfile
>   '/var/www/html/project_pfm/output/file2.txt';
>
> ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file
>   '/var/www/html/project_pfm/output/file2.txt' (Errcode: 13 - Permission
>   denied)

and this is my file permission in OS :

> root@WebPFI01:/var/www/html/project_pfm# ls -al
>
> drwxrwxrwx  3 mysql mysql      4096 Apr  6 09:35 output

thank you for your help and answer.

Comment: Check the perms on the parent directory.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu ships with AppArmor which may be causing your issues. You might want to look at some of the discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783313/how-can-i-get-around-mysql-errcode-13-with-select-into-outfile